# Откуда взялось слово "спидометр"

Tags: этимология, словообразование, синонимы

Это слово звучит как жаргонизм, состоит из двух иностранных корней, а словообразование у него характерно для русского языка. Как оно появилось в словарях? Были ли у него синонимы? Есть ли ещё подобные слова?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово *спидометр* возникло в XIX веке от английского *speed* 'скорость' и греческого *metreō* 'мерю, измеряю'. ("Большой этимологический словарь" М. В. Климовой.) Оно обозначает прибор для измерения скорости движения транспортного средства — автомобиля, мотоцикла и др. (или пройденного этим транспортным средством расстояния).

Стоит отметить, что *спидометр* было заимствовано из английского языка в виде *speedometer*, поэтому корнем в русском языке является все слово.

Сейчас *спидометр* не является жаргонизмом, однако еще в начале XX века было таковым, ведь вошло в широкое употребление лишь с развитием машиностроения.

*Спидометр* можно заменить синонимичным сочетанием *измеритель скорости*.

Подобных слов слишком много, поэтому нужно обращаться к конкретным примерам.